# How to create a static function within a functional React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to add and remove an event listener within a functional React component. The listener is added fine but is not removed when asked to be. I believe the issue is that the function I am referencing `handlemousemove` is recreated every component render and so when removeEventListener attempts to remove it, it's not the same function reference as when addEventListener added it.

I tried moving `handlemousemove` out of the component but it required access to the setState hooks generated in the component.

```
const handleMouseMove = e => {
    setYOffset(e.clientY-280)
    setXOffset(e.clientX-350)
}

const followMouse = () => {
    if (isFollowingMouse){
        setIsFollowingMouse(false)
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
    } else {
        setIsFollowingMouse(true)
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
    }
}

...

<button name="mouse" onClick={followMouse}>
    Follow Mouse
</button>
```

All branches of execution are hit here but `document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)` doesn't actually remove the event listener.

Is there a way to have a "static method" within a functional component? Is that even the issue here?

Here's a link to code sandbox with the whole code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pzrwh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old way to do it was with [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), but now that hooks have arrived [this is a better solution](https://dev.to/emeka/using-custom-hooks-in-place-of-render-props-38mf)

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [isFollowingMouse, setIsFollowingMouse] = React.useState(false);
    const [xOffset, setXOffset] = React.useState(0);
    const [yOffset, setYOffset] = React.useState(0);
    
    const handleMouseMove = e => {
        if (isFollowingMouse) {
            setYOffset(e.clientY-28);
            setXOffset(e.clientX-35);
        }
    };

    const followMouse = () => {
        setIsFollowingMouse(!isFollowingMouse);
    }

    const styles = {
        'cat': {
            'backgroundColor': 'red',
            'height': '20px',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': xOffset,
            'top': yOffset,
            'width': '20px',
            'display': isFollowingMouse ? 'block' : 'none'
        }
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ 'height': '100%' }} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
        <div style={ styles.cat }>C</div>
        <button name="mouse" onClick={followMouse}>
          Follow Mouse
        </button>
      </div>
    )
}



ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
html,
body,
#root {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I got it working by using a custom hook like in the linked article by just conditionally using the position from the hook if _isFollowing_ was true and nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think your description of the issue is spot on. A quick fix is to define the variable *handleMouseMove* outside of your *App* function - essentially making the variable *static* and not recreated every render.

Then, within the body of the function, only assign the *handleMouseMove* variable if it's currently unassigned, and set it back to null when you set *isFollowingMouse* to false.

Answer (score 0):

With React 16.7 you can use Hooks to do this:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const DraggedComponent = React.memo(
    props => {
        const [isFollowingMouse, setIsFollowingMouse] = useState(false);
        const [xOffset, setXOffset] = useState(0);
        const [yOffset, setYOffset] = useState(0);

        const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
            e => {
                if (isFollowingMouse) {
                    setYOffset(e.clientY-28);
                    setXOffset(e.clientX-35);
                }
            }, [isFollowingMouse, setYOffset, setXOffset]
        );

        useEffect(
            () => {
                document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
                return () => document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
            },
            [handleKeyDown]
        );

        const followMouse = () => setIsFollowingMouse(!isFollowingMouse);

        return (
            <div onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
                <div>C</div>
                <button name="mouse" onClick={followMouse}>
                    Follow Mouse
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
);

ReactDOM.render(<DraggedComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In this example `React.memo()` ensures that the component is only redrawn if state or properties change. Similar `useCallback()` will cache the event listener for the *mousemove* event, such that this will not be recreated only if `isFollowingMouse`, `setYOffset` or `setXOffset` change, instead of every rerender. `useEffect` will be called once the component is created, and once every time the `handleMouseMove` callback changes. Furthermore it returns a function, which is automatically called if the component is destroyed or the parameter `handleKeyDown` changes.